# JMeter "Response Times vs Threads": incorrect number of threads on graph

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

My question is related to [this JMeter plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesVsThreads/) for JMeter 5.3.

I wanted to run two thread groups one after another and then compare their response times on one graph. The idea is: each thread group starts with zero threads and gradually increase number of threads over time.

[image]

`Thread group #2` (the second one) has exactly the same options set.

In my test plan, I've set option `Run Thread Groups consecutively (i.e. one at a time)` to `true`.

Unfortunately my graph isn't rendered correctly. As you can see from below screenshot, thread number of second thread group (purple color) doesn't start at 0 and doesn't end at 100. Also, first thread group (blue), according to graph has more than 100 threads.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're incorrectly interpreting the listener results, the charts you're seeing are for **response times** and the number of active threads is on X axis, this `144` means that you were able to kick off 144 threads at peak phase of your test, the charts and Y axis are for response times per each and every [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)

You're not getting 200 threads as your ramp-up period is almost that high as the total test duration, you either need to increase the duration or reduce the ramp-up in order to get 200 threads, see [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) article for more detailed explanation.

To get better vision on what's going on look at [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) and [Response Times over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) charts separately.

Comment: In fact, I don' want to get 200 threads. Maybe I'm doing it incorrectly but my goal is to run first Thread group (with 100 threads), test my service (HTTP endpoint) for some time, gather results, finish all threads and then start second Thread group (also with 100 threads). The second Thread group will test the same service but with different parameters. Then, I want to compare both tests to check which one performs better